# How do i convert iptables rules to nftables rules?

Tags: iptables, firewall, nftables

I was trying to figure out how to convert my iptables rules to nftables rules on an Ubuntu system.

I tried to convert iptables to nftables using the automated converter, but it didn't appear to work.

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -A INPUT -s fd00:00:00::0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -D INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -D INPUT -s fd00:00:00::0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
```

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-1069-azure
$ nft -v
nftables v0.9.8 (E.D.S.)
$ iptables-translate -V
iptables-translate v1.8.7 (nf_tables)
$ ip6tables-translate -V
ip6tables-translate v1.8.7 (nf_tables)
```

#### Translate

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
nft add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname "wg0" counter accept

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
nft add rule ip nat POSTROUTING oifname "eth0" counter masquerade

iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
nft add rule ip filter INPUT ip saddr 10.0.0.0/8 udp dport 53 ct state new counter accept

ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
nft add rule ip6 filter FORWARD iifname "wg0" counter accept

ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
nft add rule ip6 nat POSTROUTING oifname "eth0" counter masquerade 

ip6tables -A INPUT -s fd00:00:00::0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
nft add rule ip6 filter INPUT ip6 saddr fd00::/8 udp dport 53 ct state new counter accept

---

iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
$ iptables-translate -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
Translation not implemented

iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
$ iptables-translate -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
Translation not implemented

iptables -D INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
$ iptables-translate -D INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
Translation not implemented

ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
$ ip6tables-translate -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
Translation not implemented

ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
$ ip6tables-translate -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
Translation not implemented

ip6tables -D INPUT -s fd00:00:00::0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
$ ip6tables-translate -D INPUT -s fd00:00:00::0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
Translation not implemented
```

#### Running

```
$ nft add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname "wg0" counter accept
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
add rule ip filter FORWARD iifname wg0 counter accept
            ^^^^^^
```

If you can improve the rules then please go for it, I want to specify ports, but I am not good with iptables or nftables.

Comment: You dismissed the use of iptables-translate / ip6tables-translate, but didn't explain how it went wrong when using it. I don't see what it could translate wrong with simple rules like these ones. Anyway even the need to translate them isn't explained. iptables won't disappear soon: it's kept around with nftables as backend.

Comment: I am getting the error that it's not implemented yet. - O3NTbN6nLgF

Comment: Didn't get such error here. What are the versions of the kernel (`uname -r`) and tools (`nft -V; iptables-translate -V`)? Also remember it has to translate separately all the commands, it doesn't translate a shell script with commas separating commands.

Comment: I realize you expect to use a translation tool without wanting to know how nftables works. Can't do this. Start with documentation there: https://wiki.nftables.org/